# What are inner-most parentheses called?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

When using the `thumbnail()` method in the Pillow (PIL) module, the following convention must be observed where two sets of (nested) parenthesis are used:

```
pil_image.thumbnail((128,128))
```

If only one set is used, Python generates the following error:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Does the inner-most parentheses have a formal name?

PS: Following also works:

```
box = 128, 128 # No parentheses needed.
pil_image.thumbnail(box)
```

Also: Is it a deficiency on part of the Python parser to not be able to figure out the intention here?

Comment: There is no "deficiency".  In the former case you need parentheses to clarify that you are not passing two positional arguments.  In the latter there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact the the parenthesis` are nested has nothing to do with anything.

It is the `,` (comma) that is important. Which is why `box = 128, 128` works and whose end result is the equivalent of `box = (128, 128)`

```
>>> box = 128, 128
>>> box
(128, 128)
>>> box = (128, 128)
>>> box
(128, 128)
```

For example, in python:

```
>>> myvar = ((128))
>>> myvar
128
```

but

```
>>> myvar = ((128),)  # notice the COMMA
>>> myvar
(128,)
```

(128,) is called a `tuple` which is something like a LIST (`mylist = []`)

One of the main differences is a LIST can be modified, a tuple cannot:

e.g.

```
mylist.append(1)  # works
myvar.append(1)  # fails
```

Comment: `myvar = ((1+3),)` results in `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` - FYI.

Comment: I am also using a terminal, in Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Don't apologize! I hope my explanation was helpful in deepening your understanding of what you are working with :)

Comment: Very much so, including the list/append distinction.

Comment: The technical term is `mutable/immutable `, lists are `mutable` while tuples are `immutable`.

Answer (score 5):

You are passing a [*tuple*](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) to the `thumbnail()` method. The distinction is as follows:

```
thumbnail((128,128))  # single tuple argument: (128,128)

thumbnail(128,128)    # two integer arguments: 128 and 128
```

Your `box` variable is also a tuple, which is why it works as well:

```
>>> box = 128, 128
>>> box
(128, 128)
>>>
>>> type(box)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its called a tuple. See this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) on tuples and other sequence types.

Answer (score 1):

`thumbnail` is a function that takes a `tuple` as its first argument. When you do `thumbnail(128, 128)`, python tries to treat `128` as a tuple (by indexing it), which it isn't, and so you get your error.

In the case of variable assignment like `box = 128, 128`, python understands that `box` is meant to be a tuple, but in the context of `thumbnail(128, 128)`, python assumes you meant to pass in two `int` arguments, and not a single `tuple`.

Comment: +1 Can you please explain a bit more how Python attempts to index 128? Thanks.

Comment: It just does, as this is what the code tells it to do. You can just do `x = 128; x[0]`. This will attempt to index an int.